# Spark ML - KMeans - org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`features`' given input columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, k-means

I am trying to analyze and cluster Chicago crime dataset with Spark ML KMeans. Below is the snippet

```
case class ChicCase(ID: Long, Case_Number: String, Date: String, Block: String, IUCR: String, Primary_Type: String, Description: String, Location_description: String, Arrest: Boolean, Domestic: Boolean, Beat: Int, District: Int, Ward: Int, Community_Area: Int, FBI_Code: String, X_Coordinate: Int, Y_Coordinate: Int, Year: Int, Updated_On: String, Latitude: Double, Longitude: Double, Location: String)
val city = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv("/chicago_city/Crimes_2001_to_present_2").as[ChicCase]

val data = city.drop("ID", "Case_Number", "Date", "Block", "IUCR", "Primary_Type", "Description", "Location_description", "Arrest", "Domestic", "FBI_Code", "Year", "Location", "Updated_On")

val kmeans = new KMeans
kmeans.setK(10).setSeed(1L)
val model = kmeans.fit(data)
```

But this is throwing the following exception

```
    org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`features`' given input columns: [Ward, Longitude, X_Coordinate, Beat, Latitude, District, Y_Coordinate, Community_Area];   
at  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:77) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:74) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:301) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformUp(TreeNode.scala:300) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionUp$1(QueryPlan.scala:190) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:200) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2$1.apply(QueryPlan.scala:204) 
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234) 
 at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234) 
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) 
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)  
 at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)  
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)   
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$QueryPlan$$recursiveTransform$2(QueryPlan.scala:204) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(QueryPlan.scala:209) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:179) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.transformExpressionsUp(QueryPlan.scala:209) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:74) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:67) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:126) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:67) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:58) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:49) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:64)   
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:2589) 
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:969)   
at org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans.fit(KMeans.scala:307)   ... 90 elided
```

The data types are either Int or Double. What could be the issue?

Comment: Do **not** include columns like "ward", "beat" or "district" that look numerica, but are ID codes. **Visualize** to make sure you get something meaningful. Spark is crap for clustering (lacking all the good algorithms) - consider using e.g. ELKI, it will be much faster. Ward boundaries: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Facilities-Geographic-Boundaries/Boundaries-Wards-2015-/sp34-6z76 - don't treat Ward numbers as numerical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spark ml data frame API, all the features columns should be collected as one single column using the *VectorAssembler* with the name of features. When you fit the model, it will try to find the *features* column, in your case, there is no such column, which is why Exception: *cannot resolve '`features`' given input columns*:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans

// assembler to collect all interesting columns into a single features column
val assembler = (new VectorAssembler().
                     setInputCols(Array("Ward", "Longitude", "X_Coordinate", "Beat", 
                                        "Latitude", "District", "Y_Coordinate", 
                                        "Community_Area")).
                     setOutputCol("features"))   

val data = assembler.transform(city)    
val kmeans = new KMeans()
val model = kmeans.fit(data)

model.getK
// res28: Int = 2     example here
```